# SQL Server pull out only data after = OR only the numerics

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

It seems that a regular expression would be ideal, yet some team members are not fond of regex...

Problem: Data in a column (from a mainframe flat file import) looks like 2 different ways

```
BreakID = 83823737237
OR
MFR BreakID=482883
```

Thus, the differences are a space before numerics, length of both the alphacharacter before the equals varies and finally the length of the numbers will vary.

Seems I have a few approaches,
1. Everything after the = sign , and trim ?
2. regex , get only the numerics?

So I found this code, in which I assume PATINDEX is standard way of doing regex in -tsql ?  what is "string" in this?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', string), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', string + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                string) + 1) AS Number
```

**How would this be solved with best practices?**

Comment: SQL Server hasn't yet implemented regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a good use case for `substring` and `replace` with `charindex`

We take the substring from everything starting with the first value after the `=` up to 99 digits (or how ever many you want to enter). We use `replace` to get rid of the leading space, if there is one.

```
select replace(substring(stringColumn,charindex('=',stringColumn) + 1,99),' ','')
```

Comment: Surely ltrim would be more efficient than replace?

Comment: Getting an error  though    `The conversion of the varchar value '82332617284' overflowed an int column.`

Comment: Probably @CaiusJard

Comment: @ChadJacobs well, youre trying to stuff a number (82.33 billion) that's bigger than the max value for an INT (2.15 billion) into an INT column. Either cut your number down or make your column bigger. It's not a failing of the solution, it's choosing an inappropriate data type for the incoming data

Comment: @scsimon also, the replace is unnecessary now we know he has a numeric column

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different answer than scsimon. I usually go this route when I have to grab the vals at the end of a string. You reverse the string and grab position of the first instance of your key value ('=' in this case). Get that position with charindex, and then grab the RIGHT() chars using that charindex value.

```
DECLARE @val1 VARCHAR(100) = 'BreakID = 83823737237'
DECLARE @val2 VARCHAR(100) = 'MFR BreakID=482883'

SELECT 
LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(@val1, CHARINDEX('=', REVERSE(@val1), 0)-1)))
,LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(@val2, CHARINDEX('=', REVERSE(@val2), 0)-1)))
```

This solution will play nice if you have weird cases, like if you have a company called `SQL=Cool` in your data and it needs an ID:

```
'SQL=CoolID = 12345'
```

and you wanted to still get 12345.

Answer (score 0):

That solution is good and versatile, although it sounds like your string will always have an `=` so you could write something more specific around that if you want to.

That solution finds the start location of the first number string:

```
PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', string)
```

And finds the location of the first non-numeric character after that number string (adding a 't' to the end of the string, in case it ends in a number which would otherwise throw an error):

```
PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', string + 't')
```

And finally it subtracts the start position of the number from the end position to find the length of the number string, and pulls that length out with substring:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', string), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', string + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                string) + 1) AS Number
```

Here "string" is a placeholder that should be replaced with your column name.  Also, the easiest way to test stuff like this in tsql is to use a variable:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(100) = 'foo bar la la la 83823737237'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @string), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @string + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                @string) + 1) AS Number
```

Output:

```
83823737237
```

Answer (score 0):

Kaizen: go for the simple solution, not the perfect one

```
SELECT substring(c, charindex('=', c), 999)
```

I'm assuming the column you're putting this in is some kind of number. Sqlserver doesn't care about leading spaces when casting to a number

If it's going in a string column then wrap it in a `ltrim()`

Now to your questions

> 1 .. trim

Sure, as above

> 2 regex...

Not implemented in sqlserver unless you use CLR

> PATINDEX ...

It's like regex but it's a very limited subset that only does searching, only returns one string index, doesn't capture, has limited/no character classes. It's more like dos/vb6 wildcards/like than regex

> ...best practice?

Look at it simply; you're getting the part of a string after an =, not landing on the moon. the best solution to minor optimisations like these is the one that requires the least amount of mental effort from the next human who takes over your job, to get up to speed with this (it'll still be being used in 20 years) :)